# Issue using selenium with chrome to print

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, for the past year I've been able to print from chrome just fine using this code in C#

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1].ToString());

IWebElement PrintButton = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector(\"print-preview-app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"print-preview-header\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"paper-button.action-button\");");
```

while trying to resolve this i went and grabbed the JS path again thinking maybe chrome changed it, but it's still not working, here's the new one:

```
IWebElement PrintButton = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector(\"body > print - preview - app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#sidebar\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"print-preview-button-strip\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"cr-button.action-button\")");
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. i know that there's some other mentions of this on SO however they all lead you to using robots which i can't do because i'm using C#, or telling you that it's not possible which it is because I've been doing it for the past year. i would prefer not using any other libraries that i don't already have since i wasn't required to do this in the past.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console window when that script runs?

Comment: Could you post the html? And have you tried using a selector and `findElement`?

Comment: I only get the error stating that the element was not found.

Comment: I was actually able to get this to work by going back to chrome 74 and using the chrome web driver 74 as well. They must have changed something in higher versions of chrome. I still would like to find the issue so I can update.